# oauth2: Request a session

Tags: python, python-3.x, oauth, oauth-2.0, python-requests

By using Python requests module, I am trying to login Linuxacademy. 
With developers tools help I'am almost managed to get payload information and URL I should use but while trying to login with

```
r =requests.post('https://lacausers.auth0.com/usernamepassword/login',params=payload)
```

Payload contains sensitive information but fields as below

```
client_id":     
"redirect_uri": 
tenant":        
connection":    
username":      
password":      
nonce":         
state":         
_intstate":     
_csrf":         
audience":      
auth0Client":   
scope":         
protocol":
```

I am getting below error

```
{"name":"ValidationError","code":"session_missing","description":"Session missing. Close all open login dialogs and try again.","statusCode":400}
```

I have closed all open login dialogs as mentioned and I logout from existing browser logins. And I am getting same error.

Seems LA using "oauth2" for authentication.

What I am trying to achieve is, I am trying to start my labservers via python - requests.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you have in payload ? where is API documentation ?

Comment: @furas I have updated my post with requested information. Please check.

Comment: Page seems has complicated system with many JavaScript scripts which change different values - ie. cookies - and requests may need them but it can't run JavaScript. Maybe try with [Selenium](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) to control web browser which will run JavaScript.